# Css Arrow Transition

Tags: html, css

I have a css arrow that points from right to left. I have the arrow first and then the text. I am trying to achieve the following transition when hovering over: Hover over, the arrow on the left disappears and appears on the right after the text. How do I go about achieving that effect that the arrow appears on the right on hover?

I am trying to achieve [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wsf0oy4a/1/) effect but in the opposite direction

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.the-arrow {
  width: 64px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.the-arrow.-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  right: 0;
}

.the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 0;
  background-color: #999;
}

.the-arrow.-left .shaft:before,
.the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  width: 0;
  background-color: #999;
}

.the-arrow.-left .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.the-arrow.-right {
  top: 3px;
}

.the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.the-arrow.-right .shaft:before,
.the-arrow.-right>.shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.the-arrow.-right .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.the-arrow .shaft {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
  will-change: transform;
}

.the-arrow .shaft:before,
.the-arrow .shaft:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.the-arrow .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.the-arrow .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.animated-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.animated-arrow:hover {
  color: #eaeaea;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before,
.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
  transform: translateX(80px);
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
  transform: translateX(200%);
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before,
.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  width: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.animated-arrow .main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.animated-arrow .main .text {
  margin: 0 0 0 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.animated-arrow .main .the-arrow {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="pivot-arrows-1" style="">


  <a class="animated-arrow arrow-c-f" href="#">

    <span class="main">
      <span class="the-arrow -right">
        <span class="shaft"></span>
      </span>

      <span class="text">
        Some cool Text
      </span>

    </span>
    <span class="the-arrow -left">
      <span class="shaft"></span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

just for the fun to make it shorter with a single pseudo and transition

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color:purple;
  font-size:2em;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;/* to be the reference for the absolute pseudo */
  display:inline-block;/* to size it and set horizontal margin */
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:black;
  margin:0 68px;
  padding:0 0.25em;
}

.animated-arrow::before {
  content:'\0003c';/* the sign < to draw edge of the arrow */
  font-size:16px;/* might need to be resized */
  /*display:inline-block; if not absolute */
  width:64px;/* that was your value, equal at the most to the margin of parent link  */
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%,currentcolor 50%,  currentcolor calc(50% + 1px) , transparent  calc(50% + 1px));/* to draw the body arrow */
  top:-0.15em;/* if needed */
  position:absolute;/* , so coordonate are easier to set */
  z-index:-1;/* let slide under the link */
  right:100%;
  transition: right  0.2s, transform 0.1s 0s;
}
.animated-arrow:hover::before {
  right:-64px;
  transform:scale(-1,1)
} 
a+a {color:gold;}
```

```html
<a class="animated-arrow arrow-c-f" href="#">Some cool Text</a> ⊛
<a class="animated-arrow arrow-c-f" href="#">Some cool Text of any length</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to achive this effect but in the opposite direction

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a solution below

Answer (score 2):

Using a single element

```css
*{  
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body{padding: 4rem}
.arrow{
  position: relative; 
  display:inline-block
}

.arrow:before,
.arrow:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.arrow:before{
  right: 100%;
  width:32px;
  height:1px;
  background: black;
}
.arrow:after{
  width:12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  right: calc( 100% + 16px );
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.arrow:hover:before{
  right: -32px
}
.arrow:hover:after{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(-1);
  right: -32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">some cool text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed some elements, and kinda cheated with the arrows.

```css
/* So it's easier to change spacing */
:root {
  --spacing: 1rem;
  --spacing-half: calc(var(--spacing) / 2);
  --spacing-quarter: calc(var(--spacing) / 4);
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  padding: var(--spacing-quarter);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text,
.animated-arrows
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.animated-arrows::before,
.animated-arrows::after {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  
  transition: left 600ms, opacity 800ms;
}

.animated-arrows::before {
  content: '⟵';
  left: 0rem;
}

.animated-arrows::after {
  content: '⟶';
  opacity: 0;
  left: calc(-1 * var(--spacing-half));
}

/* Animation changes */
.animated-arrows:hover::before {
  left: var(--spacing-half);
  opacity: 0;
}

.animated-arrows:hover::after {
  left: 0rem;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
  <a href="#">
    <div class="animated-arrows">
      <div class="text">Some cool Text</div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

So i have managed to solve the issue:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow {
  width: 64px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow.-left {
  top: 3px;
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before,
.left-arrow .the-arrow.-left>.shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
  transform: translateX(200%);
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before,
.left-arrow .animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  width: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow .shaft {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
  will-change: transform;
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow .shaft:before,
.left-arrow .the-arrow .shaft:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow:hover {
  color: #eaeaea;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow .main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow .main .text {
  margin: 0 16px 0 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow .main .the-arrow {
  position: relative;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left {
  width: 0px;
}

.the-arrow.-right {
  display: none;
}

.left-arrow .animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-right {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  right: -64px;
  top: 60%;
  padding-left: -16px
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before,
.left-arrow .the-arrow.-right>.shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="left-arrow">

  <a class="animated-arrow arrow-c-f" href="#">

    <span class="main">
      <span class="the-arrow -left">
        <span class="shaft"></span>
    </span>

    <span class="text">
        Some Text
      </span>

    </span>
    <span class="the-arrow -right">
        <span class="shaft"></span>
    </span>


  </a>
</div>
```